# Describe method of solving a problem that succeeds where past methods failed

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a problem we wish to solve. Past methods for tackling the problem have failed. Newly developed methods are effective in solving it.

What's the **adjective** or **noun** for the new methods that succeed where past methods failed? I want to emphasize that the methods are *modern* and *effective* while old methods are not.

Comment: Your own *effective* works.

Comment: @Lawrence Edited, adding bit of nuance

Comment: innovative solution

Comment: Sample sentence, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scientific contexts, the word *novel* is used.  “We describe a novel approach to reducing inflammation...”

Technically, it only means “new”, not “new and improved”, but people will assume it’s better.

Consider also *innovative* and (if you must) *groundbreaking*.

Answer (score 0):

**futuristic**

There's a problem we wish to solve. Past methods for tackling it have failed. Our new **futuristic** methods are most effective in solving it.

Runner ups: cutting-edge revolutionary visionary

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cutting%20edge

Comment: I want to avoid words that are too booster-/hype-sounding like "revolutionary" and "visionary". So "cutting-edge" is my favorite of these. It doesn't quite imply that the new methods are effective, though.

Comment: or ' like a monomolecular blade'.  A futuristic knife whose cutting edge is molecules thick!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomolecular_wire

Comment: This is unlikely to have a positive effect on technically astute readers.  "Futuristic methods" suggests a solution which is valid in theory but can't yet be put into practice because it requires more computation or more precise manufacturing than is cost-effective today.

Comment: and futuristic may imply said company has come upon parts or all of such ... and is playing their cards close.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is the noun “breakthrough”.  A solution can only be a breakthrough if the problem has proved hard to solve over a period of time.  The most familiar examples come in medical and pharmacological research.